# How to use npm package: vue-material with laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

I try to install a packages from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material-datepicker but its showing error again again

my question is how to add any npm packages in laravel 5.3 from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `npm install vue-material-datepicker --save` or add it manually to your `package.json` file and include the script in your gulpfile.js. You should be ready to go after doing those 2 steps.